# ActivityGroup VS View flipper

Tags: android, android-activity, activitygroup

I have a group of tabs. In one of the tabs, I want to display two different types of functionality.

So my question is it better to implement a activity group with child activities or just create  a view flipper and switch between views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ActivityGroup** is used to manage one or more activity example. if two different activity have different implementation but the user want to see on sharing screen basis means in first half user want to see some thing and in second have some other thing. In that case ActivityGroup comes to play

**ViewFlipper** can be used if you want to periodically change the views. Say like an automated flipping book of some sort. Though a custom-adapter gallery is much better at this.

Both have different purpose. It depends on your requirement you will choose any of them.

Answer (score 1):

i would go with a view flipper. you probably dont need the whole overhead of creating another activity. but that way will make your single activity that will hold them a bit larger. so also maybe try to implement some of the functionality inside the views you will be adding.

hope this helps.